# Proper Way to Convert Bayer Pattern to Color Image? (OpenCV, C++, RP)

Tags: image, opencv

I'm attempting to understand the basics of converting a Bayer pattern array to a color image using OpenCV in C++. I'm doing this on a Raspberry Pi, using the `opencv2` library.

I never worked with OpenCV before, or image processing in general in this capacity.

It is my understanding that a color image data can be expressed in two ways; through an array of RGB values for each pixel (or a vector), or through a [Bayer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter), in which each one of the RGB values are expressed as separate bytes (if my understanding of this is incorrect, feel free to correct me).
It is also my understanding that there are different types of Bayer patterns, and that each Bayer pattern requires a different algorithm in order to convert it to a RGB image.

The image I get from my camera I store in an array of `unsigned char`, giving me values of 0 - 255 for each pixel. If I try to create an object of type `cv::Mat` with the provided array of `unisgned char`, I am able to save & view the image in grayscale. However, I want to conver the image to a color one. The specific camera that my images come from has it's Bayer pattern listed as `RG`, which I'm assuming stands for Red-Green.

After searching online, I stumbled upon several different sources for how to perform the conversion, however I'm a bit puzzled as to how to properly do it, as I'm not well-versed in OpenCV or it's functions. The [following article](https://cppsecrets.com/users/203110310511410511510410011599115495764103109971051084699111109/C00-OpenCv-cvcvtColor.php) and many others list the `cv::cvtColor` function as the right one for the job. I am able to find and access the function from the `imgproc.hpp` file in the `opencv2` library, where I'm also able to see the arguments the function accepts as well. The function is listed as accepting two array arguments, `src` for the source image data, and `dst` for the destination image array. Both of those arguments are of the `InputArray` and `OutputArray` types respectivelly, which appear to represent templates for arrays. Does that mean I'm able to supply the array of `unsigned char`s to the function? If so, of what type should my destination array be? As far as I understand, the color image should have larger datatypes for each individual pixel, as the pixels should be represented by three bytes, not one. But my understanding may be incorrect.

After that, how would I go about converting whatever I end up with after a call to the `cv::cvtColor` function to an object of type `cv::Mat`, so I can save it as a color image? Is there a specific function for that as well?

Thank you for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Please use the c++ tag only in conjunction with specific c++ code you're facing problems with.

Comment: "how would I go about converting whatever I end up...." -- you wouldn't do anything since both the input as well as the output of `cv::cvtColor` would be a `cv::Mat`.